# Python Error Read Files <built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x0000024B969DA4D0> Python 3.10

Tags: python

I´m trying to read a `.txt` file in Python. I have this code:

```
file = open("LESEN.txt","r")
print(file)
```

When I try to run it, this error comes up:

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x0000024B969DA4D0>
```

I can remember that it works in a older Python version. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not an error. You're printing the memory address of the file handle. Perhaps you wanted `file.read()`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You're printing out the memory address of the file handle, *not* the contents of the file. You want `file.read()` for that.
2. You aren't closing the file anywhere -- it's good to use context managers for this, which will automatically handle the closing for you.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both issues:

```py
with open("LESEN.txt", "r") as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("INTERVIEW_SCHEDULES.txt","r") # You can remove r on the open(), it is read mode by default.
content = f.read()
print(content)
f.close()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?